# Regular expression for IP Address

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, ex

I need to be able to search through a log and grab IP addresses that were logged. An example log line would look like:

> [2012-06-05 11:59:52] NOTICE[14369] chan_sip.c: Registration from '' failed for 'yy.yy.yy.yyy' - No matching peer found

I need to grab the IP address listed in the `yy.yy.yy.yyy` position. With other log files, the `yy.yy.yy.yyy` would be in a different position.

I was thinking to read each line, split on `' '` and then loop through the split temporary array for: `'yy.yy.yy.yyy'`. I just don't know how to pattern match or regex for `'yy.yy.yy.yyy'` with the single quotes included. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match your ip address contained in '

```
'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
```

To iterate over all the matches in perl do:

```
while ($subject =~ m/'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'/g) {
    # matched text = $&
}
```

Group 1 of the match will only contain the IP so without the '

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) {
    my ($ip) = $line =~ /for '((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)'/
       or next;

    ... do something with $ip ...
}
```

Comment: I used this one and it pulled all my IPs that I needed. Thanks

Comment: However, with a normal Log entry like --- 2012-05-12 08:10:20,481 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh-iptables] Ban yyy.yyy.yy.yyy
 -- i cannot get the Ban IP with ((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)

Comment: huh, yes you can (if those "y"s are digits)

Comment: @ikegami Oh, didn't see that part, my mistake.

Comment: @ikegami a line like `[Sat Jun 16 21:32:55 2012] [error] [client 208.179.17.39] File does not exist: /var/www/html/` will not be parsed with the above for loop. i tried with the following `opendir( DIR, "/var/log/httpd" ) or die $!;

while( my $file = readdir( DIR ) ) {

  next unless( -f "/var/log/httpd/$file" );

  if( $file =~ /error\_log/ ) {

    open( LOG, "/var/log/httpd/$file" );

    while( <LOG> ) {

      if( $_ =~ /File/ ) {
        my ( $ip )  = $_ =~ /for ((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)/
          or next;
        print "IP ==> $ip\n";
      }
    }
    close( LOG );
  }
}
`

Comment: Correct, it won't. It's not even close to what you said should be matched.

Comment: @ikegami right, it worked for what you said it was going to work for. i was trying to extrapolate and use it elsewhere but apparently I failed. I used buckely's for what i needed in this one. I cant even find information on the syntax you used

Comment: @user1438087, well, you removed the quote, but you left `for` in. `for` isn't in the string you're string to match.

Comment: @ikegami hahha i completely over looked it. I was trying TOO hard to understand it and I have no clue why the `for` is in there. so `my ( $ip ) = $_ =~ /client ((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)/ or next;` works. thanks again.